# Capturing one column values with another corresponding column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cost_m1': [10, 11, 140], 'cost_m2': [130, 90, 110], 'cost_m3': [80, 110, 120],
                    'prob_m1': [0.1, 0.11, 0.25], 'prob_m2':[0.13, 0.19, 0.19], 'prob_m3':[0.21, 0.11, 0.14] })
df = df.reset_index()  # make sure indexes pair with number of rows
```

I have got the dataframe above where costs and their corresponding probabilities are given.
What I want is the following output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Desired Dataframe]

Comment: kindly explain how the results are computed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```py
df1 = ( pd.DataFrame(
    [sorted(((df.loc[i,f'cost_m{j}'], df.loc[i,f'prob_m{j}']) for j in range(1,4)), reverse=True) 
    for i in range(len(df))]) )
df1 = ( pd.DataFrame(
    [df1.iloc[i,].explode().to_numpy() for i in range(len(df1))], 
    columns=pd.Series([(f'{nth}_largest_cost', f'{nth}_largest_corres_prob') for nth in ('1st','2nd','3rd')]).explode()) )
df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns='index'), df1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   cost_m1  cost_m2  cost_m3  prob_m1  prob_m2  prob_m3  1st_largest_cost  1st_largest_corres_prob  2nd_largest_cost  2nd_largest_corres_prob  3rd_largest_cost  3rd_largest_corres_prob
0       10      130       80     0.10     0.13     0.21               130                     0.13                80                     0.21                10                     0.10
1       11       90      110     0.11     0.19     0.11               110                     0.11                90                     0.19                11                     0.11
2      140      110      120     0.25     0.19     0.14               140                     0.25               120                     0.14               110                     0.19
```

Explanation:

- create a new dataframe that pairs cost and prob for m1, m2 and m3 and sorts in reverse
- create another dataframe using a list of exploded rows (to get interleaved cost/prob columns) from the previous dataframe together with the desired new column labels, and concat it to the right of the original dataframe with the column named `index` dropped.

Answer (score 2):

You can first create an intermediate DataFrame with a MultiIndex, then perform indexing lookup using the sorted order of "Cost":

```
import numpy as np

df2 = (df
   .drop(columns='index', errors='ignore')
   .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1))
 )

idx = (np.arange(len(df2))[:, None], np.argsort(-df2['cost']))

out = df.join(pd.concat([
 pd.DataFrame(df2['cost'].to_numpy()[idx], index=df.index).add_prefix('cost_'),
 pd.DataFrame(df2['prob'].to_numpy()[idx], index=df.index).add_prefix('prob_')
], axis=1)
)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
   index  cost_m1  cost_m2  cost_m3  prob_m1  prob_m2  prob_m3  cost_0  cost_1  cost_2  prob_0  prob_1  prob_2
0      0       10      130       80     0.10     0.13     0.21     130      80      10    0.13    0.21    0.10
1      1       11       90      110     0.11     0.19     0.11     110      90      11    0.11    0.19    0.11
2      2      140      110      120     0.25     0.19     0.14     140     120     110    0.25    0.14    0.19
```